# sqlldr.exe not working for Windows 10

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I have recently installed Oracle Database Client (12.1.0.2.0)(winx64) with Custom installation and by selecting only database utilities which will include SQL*Loader among with the other things.
But when I am trying to execute sqlldr.exe then I am getting below error :

[image]

After searching on net I got common solution from all the sites i.e  in bin folder, copying oraodm12.dll and renaming it to oranfsodm12.dll could be a fix.
see the below site references:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/3652577?start=0&tstart=0%20

http://wiki.ispirer.com/sqlways/troubleshooting-guide/oracle/import/data-not-loaded

As like others it works for me as well but after that I am getting same new error for **oraclsce.dll**

[image]

It seems other people didn't get this error after applying solution mentioned above. I tried to search how to fix this error but I didn't get proper solution.

Any help for this will be appreciated.

Comment: Do a new Administrator type Installation - you definitely made something wrong with Custom choices.

Comment: @DmitriyYankin which choices I need to select? Previously I had selected database utilities only

Comment: Choose "Administrator" type - it will be enough. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ntcli/oracle-database-client-installation-types.html#GUID-C8EE50B6-CD75-44C7-90C5-5D3105EBCECE

Comment: This suggestion won't help you fix the issue, but nonetheless: I prefer installing the **database** over the client. It is 11gXE I'd suggest - a small footprint, comes with *everything* you need (SQL Loader included). You don't even have to use it, ever - set its services not to start at all (for example, set them to "Manual"), but - having it installed, you'll have any utility you need (loader, data pump, original exp/imp ...), and you don't have to care whether you chose the right client (instant or *full*), its options ... nothing.

Comment: @Littlefoot, I think this would be an overkill.

Comment: Well, that depends on someone's point of view, @Wernfried. Just mind ZIP file size: 11gXE is 320 MB, 11gR2 Client is 615 MB. I especially *hate* installing Instant Client, as there are too often things that are missing. You know - at the moment, instant client is OK, but then I need *this* and I need *that*, so let's install those from client ... nah. I'm just happy with XE - installs everything at once. I'm not saying that *everyone* (or *anyone*) should do what I'm doing. I was just sharing my thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

That is a known bug ([Bug 17548895](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1589205.1&id=17548895)) in Oracle Universal Installer.

Oracle provides a workaround for it:

> ```
> WORKAROUND INFORMATION
> ======================
> Workarounds include:
> To avoid the issue in the first place, explicitely select "Oracle NET"
> component during install
>
> After the fact, you can 
> a) do another custom install into the same home, and select "Oracle NET"
> or
> b) copying ORACLSCE12.DLL from an existing install into OH\bin also resolves
> the issue.
> ```

However, `ORACLSCE12.DLL` is not the only file which is missing (that is the issue you are facing) so the workaround b) is not suitable. Additionally to your desired components you have to select "Oracle Net" in the Oracle Universal Installer, then it should work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is another bug in Oracle Universal Installer. Thanks for providing this as answer. However, as far as I know it applies only to version 12.1. Bug 17548895 applies to all versions above 12.1 - but I am not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

I tried selecting different options and copying oraclsce12.dll around and found the following solution which is a combination of Wernfrieds answer and this thread: [sqlldr cannot start because oranfsodm12.dll is missing](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3652577):

- Step 1: Renaming  oraodm12.dll to oranfsodm12.dll
- Step 2: Copy
  ORACLSCE12.DLL into your OH-folder from the installation process

Im using oracle client version 12.1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is a bug or not in this version Oracle Client 12.2.1 64 bit. Today i found the same problem when launch sqlldr. This is the message error looks like
[oranfsodm12.dll is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Moacq.png)

I solve this problem by renaming file **oraodm12.dll** and renaming it to **oranfsodm12.dll**. The file is located in C:\app\client<user name>\product\12.1.0\client_1\BIN