# Oracle Instant Client 12.2 installation (not seeing SQL*Loader)

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, oracleclient

I am currently running the setup file. I went through it and chose to do a **custom** installation. By doing so, I was given a list of utilities to choose from. Unfortunately, I do not see Sql*Loader anywhere in sight.

Here is a blog from Oracle stating that is should be included in the installation: https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-122-now-has-sqlloader-and-data-pump

Where is it? Any information would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 12c, **instant** client contains SQL*Loader.

Download it (for [Windows 64-bit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html), it is called "instantclient-tools-windows.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip")

- all versions are [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/downloads/index.html)

Read [Oracle Instant Client 12.2 now has SQL*Loader and Data Pump](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/oracle-instant-client-122-now-has-sqlloader-and-data-pump) written by Jim Stenoish, Senior Director of Software Development;

Comment: Could you also provide the link for Windows 32-bit version?

Answer (score 1):

To anyone who comes across this in the future wondering where you can find SQL Loader for other versions of the client (in my case, version 19, the latest):

You have to scroll down and download SQL Loader separately as part of the optional Tools Package (second row):

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/winx64-64-downloads.html

[image]

Unzip the download and move the folder to, say, the folder where you installed Oracle Instant Client. Then, you can simply add it to your `PATH` variable so that the `sqlldr` command is accessible from the command-line.

Answer (score 0):

You must select **Oracle Database Utilities** in order to get SQL*Loader

Note, due to [Bug 17548895](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?parent=DOCUMENT&sourceId=1589205.1&id=17548895) in the Oracle Universal Installer you also have to select **Oracle Net**

See also [sqlldr.exe not working for Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071702/sqlldr-exe-not-working-for-windows-10/52083851#52083851)